# mongoDB - find by id after aggregation

Tags: javascript, mongodb

i have an a nested array. preformed aggregation to make the subarray the new root.

```
Category.aggregate([{$unwind: "$SubCats"}, { $replaceRoot: {newRoot: '$SubCats'}} ])
```

now i need to find by id.

using this would return empty reuslts:

```
Category.aggregate([{$unwind: "$SubCats"}, { $replaceRoot: {newRoot: '$SubCats'}}, {$match: {_id: `${req.params.id}`}} ])
```

using `$elemMatch` is not supported for my atlas tier. and using `findById()` gives this erro 'Category.aggregate(...).findById is not a function'

array:

```
[
 {
     _id: '61cae5daf5bfbebd7cf748ee'
     title: 'category 1',
     SubCats: [
         {
             _id: '61cae5daf5bfbebd7cf748ef'
             name: 'subcat 1',
             image: '/assets/images/vr-box-6203301_1920.jpg',
         },
         {
             _id: '61cae5daf5bfbebd7cf748fb'
             name: 'subcat 2',
             image: '/assets/images/galaxy-s20_highlights_kv_00.jpg',
         },
     ]
 },
]
```

after aggregation:

```
[
 {
   _id: '61cae5daf5bfbebd7cf748ef'
   name: 'subcat 1',
   image: '/assets/images/vr-box-6203301_1920.jpg',
 },
 {
    _id: '61cae5daf5bfbebd7cf748fb'
    name: 'subcat 2',
    image: '/assets/images/galaxy-s20_highlights_kv_00.jpg',
 },
]
```

Comment: Is the `_id` field really a sting like `'61cae5daf5bfbebd7cf748ef'` or actually an ObjectId, i.e. `ObjectId("61cae5daf5bfbebd7cf748ef")`?

Comment: Instead of `$unwind` and `$match` you may use [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/)

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit its ObjectId()

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit can you show an example please. for `$filter`.  thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so i needed to install mongodb from npm i didnt have it installed intially because i was conncting to a cloud mongodb databasse.

so

```
npm i mongodb
```

then import

```
import mongodb from 'mongodb'
const {ObjectId} = mongodb
```

and then this is what worked:

```
Category.aggregate([{$unwind: "$SubCats"}, { $replaceRoot: {newRoot: '$SubCats'}}, {$match: {_id: ObjectId(req.params.id)} } ])
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just move the `$match` stage to be at the start of the pipeline? it will also improve the pipeline's performance as you won't unwind and replace root on many irrelevant documents:

```
Category.aggregate([ {$match: {_id: `${req.params.id}`}}, {$unwind: "$SubCats"}, { $replaceRoot: {newRoot: '$SubCats'}} ])
```

If for some reason you don't want to do this then you have to preserve the original id field throughout the pipeline, specifically through the `$replaceRoot` stage, like so:

```
Category.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "$SubCats"
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: {
                $mergeObjects: [
                    '$SubCats',
                    { original_id: "$_id" }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {original_id: `${req.params.id}`}
    }
])
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. but im still getting emtpy results : `[]`

Comment: make sure `_id` is string, (assuming it's not) you'll need to cast `req.params.id` to `ObjectId`: ```{original_id:  new ObjectId(req.params.id)}```

Answer (score 0):

Field `_id` is an `ObjectId`, thus the query must be like this:

```
Category.aggregate([
   { $unwind: "$SubCats" }, 
   { $replaceRoot: {newRoot: '$SubCats'} }, 
   { $match: {_id: ObjectId(`${req.params.id}`) } } 
])
```

But you simply use

```
Category.aggregate([
   { $match: {"SubCats._id": ObjectId(`${req.params.id}`) } } 
])
```

or use `$filter`

```
Category.aggregate([
   {
      $set: {
         SubCats: {
            $filter: {
               input: "$SubCats",
               cond: { $eq: ["$$this._id", ObjectId(`${req.params.id}`)] }
            }
         }
      }
   }
])
```